# How can pass the stdout to the last comand?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, xargs

I am trying a search with `locate` only in the current directory, for do this I am using the following approach:

```
locate file | pwd | xargs grep
```

the problem is that the locate results are lost into a grep, how can do this for work, it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The place of `pwd` is not correct. You can try it like this:

```
locate file |  xargs grep `pwd`
```

but why do not use just `ls`

```
ls|grep file
```

Comment: this `locate file |  xargs grep `pwd`` doesn't return the same that `ls|grep file`, any idea, I am only do a shell exercices, no the best way of do this.

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES this happen probably because you have in current directory also files with the same substring in filename.

Comment: Also, locate gives the full path of the file, ls only the filename.

Comment: @seshoumara Well, you know what directory you're in. Also, the `locate` database is updated daily (weekly on some systems), which means that you may well get severely outdated information from it.

Comment: Also note that `locate file` will not be the same as `ls | grep file` if the current directory's pathname contains `file` in any component.

Comment: `printf "%s\n" $(pwd)/*file*` might do it

Answer (score 0):

When searching for files and folders, I prefer the [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command, because it is more flexible.

```
#to search only in the current folder (without going to subfolders)
find "$(pwd)" -maxdepth 1 -name "*file*"

#to search in the current folder and subfolders
find "$(pwd)" -name "*file*"
```

Note that `find "$(pwd)"` is used to print the full path of what find returns. You could use `find .`, if you want a relative path to your current folder.

If nothing was found, try using `-iname` instead.